# Understanding how c# properties work

Tags: c#

Why does this work:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<Main_key, Main_data> entry in mainTable.OrderBy(key=> key.Value.username)
{
    ...
}
```

And this doesn't:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<Main_key, Main_data> entry in mainTable.OrderBy(key=> key.Value.GetType().GetProperty("username"))
{
    ...
}
```

Shouldn't it be the same?

Comment: No, `key.Value.GetType().GetProperty("username").GetValue(key.Value, null)` will be the equivalent

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Your comment should be the answer with possibly a reference to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp

Comment: `GetProperty` returns `PropertyInfo` not the value of the property.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thank you. I'm getting a "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error though. Any idea why? The property does exist

Comment: @Cornwell [This should help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) in case of `NullReferenceException`. Am pretty sure something is null, use debugger to inspect it.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thank you. One last question, Could you please check my edit. GetProperties().length is returning 0. Any idea why?

Comment: @Cornwell your `username` is declared as field, not a property. Declare it as `public string username {get; set;}`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thank you. I understand now. If you create an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `GetType().GetProperty()` it returns something called [PropertyInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It is not same as the property value. As the name suggests, it can be expanded as "Property Information".

So it returns a object which tells you many useful information about the Property like *What is the type of the property*, *Whether it has getter/setter*, *Which class it lives in* and so forth.

Since `PropertyInfo` object just gives the general information about the property it can't be the value of your property, To get your property value you need to call [PropertyInfo.GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.GetValue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

So equivalent code for reading the property value would be:

```
type.GetProperty("YourPropertyName").GetValue(yourInstance, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

No, `GetProperty("username")` returns the [`PropertyInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) associated with with the `username` property. This should be the same object for all values in your collection (assuming they are the same type). To get the value of this property for each object you'd have to call [`GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty(v=vs.110).aspx) and pass in an instance of the object whose property value you'd like to return, like this:

```
foreach (var entry in mainTable.OrderBy(key => key.Value.GetType().GetProperty("username").GetValue(key.Value, null))
{
    ...
}
```

<sup>Note the use of implicit typing with the [`var` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) for brevity.</sup>

However, I really wouldn't do this unless you *really* have to; using reflection is slow compared to direct property access.

Also note, if you're trying to run this against a Linq-to-Entities provider or similar, this simply won't work. That's because the Linq provider needs to translate the expression you provide to a SQL query, and `GetType`, `GetProperty`, and `GetValue` simply don't have a SQL equivalent (at least not one that the Linq provider can use).

---

Also note, in your example, `username` is actually a field rather than a property. In that case, you'd use [`GetField("username")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53seyfee(v=vs.110).aspx) instead (which returns a [`FieldInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
foreach (var entry in mainTable.OrderBy(key => key.Value.GetType().GetField("username").GetValue(key.Value))
{
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you could simply use [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx), which will allow you to write something that *looks* like a normal property / field access, but will in fact cause the compiler to emit reflection code similar to what's described above:

```
foreach (var entry in mainTable.OrderBy(key => ((dynamic)key.Value).username)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm getting a "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error though. Any idea why? The property does exist

Comment: @Cornwell Is one of your values null? You might try something like `key.Value == null ? "" : key.Value.GetProperty...`

Comment: Still the same.. Please check my edit. GetProperties().length is returning 0. Any idea why?

Comment: @Cornwell Please see my updated answer for some alternatives.